# Partially Deserializing a complex java object

Tags: java, serialization

I have a java class hierarchy as follows.

```
public class Results{
    private String _query;
    private CachedRowSetImpl _resultSet;
    //... getter setters
}
```

I've serialized `List<Results> resultList`, consider this List contains 100 items and each _resultSet having more than 1000 records. I have 2 questions,

1. When we deserialize this object, my application memory will hold the entire object and will it create heap size problem?
2. If it will create resource problem, when I deserialize, can I ignore `_resultSet` being deserialized meaning just query is enough?

Correct me, if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: You can implement `Externalizable` and use its `readExternal` and `writeExternal` accordingly

Comment: If you can ignore `_resultSet` while deserialization, why serialize it then? Just make it `transient`.

Comment: it depends on your requirement that you have to ignore `_resultSet ` or not. if you have to ignore then as suggested by @SashiKant you can use `Externalizable` for your own way of `serialization` and `deserialization`. or simply you can make that variable **transient**.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal: He doesn't' always want to ignore that during deserialization, so I dont think transient will solve his problem.

Comment: The thing is, I need `_resultSet ` in one process, and not in the other process, so I cannot do ignore this to be serialized.

Comment: @Pasupathi Then please go with `Externalizable`, checking the process in the `readExternal` method

Comment: Ya, I don't know about it. So I'm working on it Sashi Kant. Seems it would help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implement `Externalizable`,your `readExternal` will look somewhat like :

```
     public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException,  
         ClassNotFoundException {  
             _query=(String) in.readObject();  
            if(//yourCondition){
             _resultSet=(CachedRowSetImpl) in.readObject();  
            }
         }
```

Comment: I'm struck how to do this, when `serializeObjectInputStream.readObject()` the `readExternal` will be called, then only new `Results` object will be created, where can I give value for validation like you mentioned, in `//yourCondition` if possible can you give an idea.?

Answer (score 0):

You should implement Serializable.
The modifier "transient" can be used to ignore fields during serialization.
I do not know what contained in CachedRowSetImpl but when you ignore that then only 100 String objects will not likely cause heap problem.

```
public class Results implements Serializable{
    private String _query;
    private transient CachedRowSetImpl _resultSet;
    //... getter setters
}
```

Comment: OP doesnt always want to ignore that, it should be conditional based on the resultset size

Comment: I need _resultSet in one process, and not in the other process. So as  Sashi Kant said, `transient` won't help me.